# new vs2008 user

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to build a release version of my project. Our prof made us create a static library which i built using debug version.

then i made a release version of that static library using /mt as my c runtime

now in my test application (release version) I use the same runtime option and add that static library and also ignore the libcmd.lib in the ignore settings for the linker.

i resolved most of the problem

this is the last part
lnk4075 /edit and continue due to /opt:icf specification compositelib.lib (my staticlib)
lnk2001 unresolved external symbol _winmain@16. libcmtd.lib

these are the last two that i can't seem to figure out.

Comment: the actual error messages are usually pretty helpful if you read them and try to understand what they mean.

Comment: he does not answer my question in time. that is why i am using this place to see if i can get helps. if i am building release version should it matter if i use /mt or /mtd? as long as i use that through out

Answer (score 0):

add libcmt.lib to ignore list for release version.